# Structure of $E_\text{tor}(\mathbb{Q})$ for an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

For $E$ an elliptic over $\mathbb{Q}$, I want to see the structure of $E_\text{tor}(\mathbb{Q})$.

First of all, $E(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})[m]=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, thus $E_{\text{tor}}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})\cong\lim\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Also by using weil pairing, I can see that for any $m>2$, $E(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})[m]$ is not contained in $E_{\text{tor}}(\mathbb{Q})$.

I want to ask how to prove $E_\text{tor}(\mathbb{Q})$ is either isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ or isomorphic to the direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks!

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I mean $m> 2$.

Comment: Won't the properties of the Weil pairing immediately give you this? Any pairing only involving points from $E(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}$ is rational, hence of multiplicative order $\le2$. On the other hand when restricted to $E(\overline{\Bbb{Q}})[m]$ the Weil pairing takes all the values in $\mu_m$.

Comment: Possibly a bit more precisely. By the structure theory of finitely generated abelian groups any finite subgroup of $E(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}\simeq \Bbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus\Bbb{Z}_{d_2}$ with $d_1\mid d_2$. The Weil pairing restricted to that subgroup takes as its values all of $\mu_{d_1}$. Hence $d_1\mid 2$.

Comment: Dear @JyrkiLahtonen. Restrict Weil pairing to $\mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{d_1}$, by Galois invariant, the image is contained in $\{1,-1\}$ and it is also contained in $\mu_{d_1}$, why does this imply $d_1∣2$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And you mean the answer is either $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{d_2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{d_2}\cong\frac{1}{d_2}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I find [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639647/how-to-determine-the-group-structure-of-e-mathbbr-for-an-elliptic-curve-e?rq=1), but it concerns $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{Q}$, and the proof is complicated.

Comment: Only if you already know that the torsion group is finite. I guess it's not quite as obvious as I thought. But I think you split it into cases bby how much 2-torsion there is and, then conclude. Past midnight here, and I have consumed my Friday night Laphroaig, so I will take a break.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Good night！I can't quite see why the torsion group is finite. Also, I know finite subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is finite, but subgroup of a direct product of groups is not direct product of subgroups.

Comment: Finiteness of the torsion subgroup is a non-trivial theorem (Mazur classified the possibilities). I don't think it follows from this alone.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Actually, I am trying to learn Mazur's proof of his classification, and the question I ask is the first step..., I think my question is trivial, though I can't see it.

Comment: You don't need Mazur's theorem to see that $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}$ is finite. This follows from the fact that $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}$ injects into $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)_{tors}$. By formal groups this in turn injects into $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)/E_r(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ for large enough $r$. The only hard part remaining is showing $[E(\mathbb{Q}_p) : E_0(\mathbb{Q}_p]$ is finite - but there is a trick in this case, see Silverman Ex7.6.